# Lime in Visual Studio Code - setup failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe, openfl, lime-haxe

I'm stumped and need a bit of help. I'm trying to setup vscode for lime/OpenFL, but keep getting this error:

> Lime completion setup failed. Is the lime command available? Try running "lime setup" or changing the "lime.executable" setting.

I did "lime setup", lime is actually working, I can even build. But no autocomplete in vscode, no nothing. Even within the same file, "Go to Definition" does not work.
As for lime.executable, I can't find where that is...

Can any of you guys please help me figure this out? :)

EDIT: I found the lime.executable thing in the extension directory > lime > package.json. I don't really see a problem there tho.

> "lime.executable": {
>                       "description": "The Lime executable to call in tasks and for `lime display`. Can be multiple arguments separated by spaces or a path to an executable.",
>                       "type": "string",
>                       "default": "lime"
>                   }

EDIT2: the full error goes:
`Error: Command failed: lime display neko dev
Error: You must have a "project.xml" file or specify another valid project file when using the 'display' command`

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:217:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:510:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the error is shown despite the lime command working, there is likely another reason it is failing, such as a missing Haxelib. Click the error messages' "Show Full Error" button to open the dev console to see exactly why it's failing.

Comment: There's certainly something missing somewhere. Sadly, the quote I made is pretty much the full error :/ there's also a `e.onDidNotificationChange` @ /C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2217 mentioned, but it's not very helpful, is it?

Comment: Are you sure that's all that's in the dev console? There should be a full stack trace, including the arguments used for the "lime display" command and why it failed.

Comment: Dammit, you're right, there is! `Error: Command failed: lime display neko dev
Error: You must have a "project.xml" file or specify another valid project file when using the 'display' command`

Answer (score 1):

> lime display neko dev

The extension should run `lime display neko`, not `lime display neko dev` by default, perhaps you added "dev" to your target flags? Click the button at the bottom that says "Edit Target Flags" (it looks like a list) and make sure that it is clear.

Comment: Wow thanks! No error anymore, autocomplete works \o/ but still no Go To Definition for some reason... Any idea on what might still be going wrong?

Comment: Go To Definition sometimes doesn't work for me too. Maybe its related to the https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/issues/106