# What does a task with "type": "lime" do in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lime

I came back to an old project Visual Studio Code recently and I'm trying to figure out how it works. I opened my tasks.json file and there's a task with "type": "lime". What does this do? I looked over the [tasks.json schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix) and according to that, this shouldn't be a valid value. I assume that it has something to do with the Lime extension, but I couldn't find what that does either. Is there documentation for this somewhere? I did a Google search and I couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Could be for the lime testing framework, but I don't see anything on the linked page now. Do you remember if you were looking at something PHP-related by chance?

Comment: Possibly related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995823/lime-in-visual-studio-code-setup-failed